# iOS is it possible to have status bar that is half light and half dark

Tags: ios, statusbar

I have status bar where left part is on dark background and I have there light text content. But right part of status bar background is on the other hand white and I would like to have there black text.

Is it possible to set different colours of status bar content in left and right half. In left I have dark menu and in right I have content on white background.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is not possible.

Comment: I found solution but I have Split View Controller and then I can override in preferredStatusBarStyle differently in Master and Detail view controller. In general I think it will not be possible while having single view controller

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I found solution but I have Split View Controller and then I can override in preferredStatusBarStyle differently in Master and Detail view controller. In general I think it will not be possible while having single view controller

Comment: Wow. This really confuses me since the split view controller itself is just a single view controller. I do not get how it adopts the status bar styles from its master as well as its detail view controller.

Comment: I consider whether it will be possible to add 2x container views with child view controllers that have transparent backgrounds, and are layout only under status bar appropriately in the left and right side. Then in each this child View controller set different preferredStatusBarStyle

Comment: This won't work since using child view controllers means that there is a parent (like in the split view case). And this parent is responsible for the status bar style. It can only adopt the style from **one** of its children. That's exactly why the working split view example confuses me. :)

Comment: But is not SplitViewController just Container View Controller with two child view controllers under the hood

Comment: I understand that. But the split view controller is also just some container view controller with child view controllers under the hood... ;)